# Could the empty set be complete partial order?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

According to the definition, $(S,\leq)$ is cpo when each totally ordered subset of $S$ has supremum. I'm sure $(\emptyset,\emptyset)$ is a total order, but I don't know whether $(\emptyset,\emptyset)$ is cpo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the definition that you have given, the answer is no. It is not complete.

However, one has to ask whether or not the empty set is defined to be a partial order to begin with; if not then not only the question is moot, but the empty set itself is not a totally ordered subset of any partial order. Therefore we do not require that the empty set has a bound.

---

In mathematics definitions are not absolute in most cases. And exactly these sort of end-cases are the common differences between two available definitions. If you define a partial order to be any set, including the empty set, which has a certain relation attached to it; and you define a complete partial order if **every** subset has a least upper bound, then indeed $\varnothing$ is **not** a complete linear order.

If we do not allow the empty set to be considered a partial order, then every complete partial order has a minimum, which is the least upper bound of the empty set; so we don't need to exclude the empty set from our definition of completeness. (Note that under this definition the real numbers are not complete, but if we add $\pm\infty$ they are complete)

Another alternative is to modify the definition that every bounded set has a least upper bound/greatest lower bound. In this definition the real numbers are complete again, but we still have to exclude the empty set, because it is bounded by every real number.

**To sum up**, mathematics is not context free. Everything depends on the definitions you are working with, which may vary slightly from context to context.

Comment: $\emptyset$ is a totally ordered subset of $\emptyset$. By definition, $\emptyset$ should have supremum on relation $\emptyset$, but what is it?

Comment: No, every non-empty set has a supremum. And again, it depends on your definition of partial orders. In many places we require partial orders to be non-empty, thus excluding the empty set. If you use other definitions, the consequences are different.

Comment: That means the definition of cpo should add the limit of "non-empty set"?

Comment: It depends on your context.

Comment: So, can I say the supremum of $\emptyset$ depends on context too? For $\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty,-\infty\}$, $\mathrm{sup}(\emptyset)=-\infty$ and $\mathrm{inf}(\emptyset)=+\infty$, but for context of $\emptyset$, $\mathrm{sup}(\emptyset)$ and $\mathrm{inf}(\emptyset)$ are not existed?

Comment: Yes. If you only discuss $\Bbb R$, then $\pm\infty$ do not exist, and therefore $\varnothing$ do not have a least upper bound, or greatest lower bound.

Comment: The OP *provided* a definition of complete partial order in the question: it is "each totally ordered subset", not "each totally ordered nonempty subset". According to the OP's definition, every cpo has a greatest and a least element, and the empty po is not complete. I'm not familiar with complete partial orders, but certainly the standard definition of complete *lattice* requires a greatest and a least element.

Comment: @bof: And if you visit the Wikipedia page about complete partial orders you will see that the requirement that every non-empty directed set has a least upper bound. But you are right. I will edit the answer in a bit (I have to leave in a minute).